# How can I set DB for a particular application in Glassfish?

Tags: web-applications, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have two different applications( For eg. App1 and App2) deployed in glassfish. I want to use two different databases (For eg. DB1 and DB2) for those applications.

`DB1 for App1 and DB2 for App2`. Is it possible?

If it is how can I configure this in Glassfish or Do I need to handle this in my code (I'm working in EJB3.0)?

Its urgent. Please reply asap.

Answer (score 1):

In glassfish admin console create two jdbc resources (eg. `jdbc/db1` and `jdbc/db2`) with your db configurations. Then in your session bean inject db connection in this way:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/db1")
private DataSource ds;
```

However you can set your db configuration directly in the code by using [`@DataSourceDefinition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html) annotation.